# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have the following code:

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
var data = c.DownloadString("https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker");
//Console.WriteLine(data);
JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);
maskedTextBox11.Text = o["high"];
```

But it's giving the error in the title.

Comment: Would be better if we see your code..

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: What about explicitly casting it as mentioned!? maskedTextBox11.Text = (string)o["high"];

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are just required to add `o["high"].ToString();` instead of `o["high"];` since `JObject[]` returns a `JToken` and you are trying to assign `maskedTextBox11.Text`, which is a `string`, with it.

If you want the `ToString()` of the object represented by the token you can do it as the following:

```
MyType obj = o["high"].ToObject<MyType>();
string s = obj.ToString();
```

Answer (score 7):

`high` is in the object `ticker`.

```
{
  "ticker": {
    "high": 730,
    "low": 671,
    "avg": 700.5,
    "vol": 9878677.9487,
    "vol_cur": 14084.99793,
    "last": 708.1,
    "buy": 708.1,
    "sell": 707.123,
    "updated": 1391962469,
    "server_time": 1391962470
  }
}
```

So first locate the correct object and then cast it to a string.

your code will be something like this:

```
maskedTextBox11.Text = (string)o["ticker"]["high"];
```

Alternatively, you also use `dynamic`

```
dynamic o = JObject.Parse(data);
maskedTextBox11.Text = o.ticker.high;
```